# Pandas apply function to column taking the value of previous column

Tags: python, pandas

I have to create a timeseries using column values for computing the Recency of a customer.

The formula I have to use is R(t) = 0 if the customer has bought something in that month, R(t-1) + 1 otherwise.

I managed to compute a dataframe

```
    CustomerID  -1  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0   17850   0   0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   13047   0   0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
2   12583   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   14688   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
4   15311   0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
3750    15471   0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
3751    13436   0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
3752    15520   0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
3753    14569   0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
3754    12713   0   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
```

In which there's a 0 if the customer has bought something in that month and one otherwise. The column names indicate a time period, with the column "-1" as a dummy column.

How can I replace the value in each column with 0 if the current value is 0 and with the value of the previous column + 1 otherwise?

For example, the final result for the second customer should be 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 2

I know how to apply a function to a column, but I don't know how to make that function use the value from the previous column.

Comment: Can you please elaborate `if the current value is 0 and the value of the previous column + 1 otherwise?`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma `f(x) := 0 if x == 0 else f(x-1) + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use apply function to iterate throw columns or rows of dataframe and do manipulation.

```
def apply_function(row):
    return [item if i == 0 else 0 if item == 0 else item+row[i-1] for i,item in enumerate(row)]

new_df = df.apply(apply_function, axis=1, result_type='expand')
new_df.columns = df.columns  # just to set previous column names
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you insist on using the column structure? It is common with time series to use rows, e.g., a dataframe with columns CustomerID, hasBoughtThisMonth. You can then easily add the Recency column by using a pandas transform().

I cannot yet place comments hence the question in this way.

Edit: here is another way to go by. I took two customers as an example, and some random numbers of whether or not they bought something in a month.

Basically, you pivot your table, and use a groupby+cumsum to get your result. Notice that I avoid your dummy column in this way.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

# Make example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID': [1]*12+[2]*12,
                   'Month': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]*2,
                   'hasBoughtThisMonth': np.random.randint(2,size=24)})

# Make Recency column by finding contiguous groups of ones, and groupby
contiguous_groups = df['hasBoughtThisMonth'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

df['Recency']=df.groupby(by=['CustomerID', contiguous_groups], 
            as_index=False)['hasBoughtThisMonth'].cumsum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is

```
    CustomerID  Month  hasBoughtThisMonth  Recency
0            1      1                   1        1
1            1      2                   1        2
2            1      3                   0        0
3            1      4                   0        0
4            1      5                   1        1
5            1      6                   1        2
6            1      7                   1        3
7            1      8                   1        4
8            1      9                   1        5
9            1     10                   0        0
10           1     11                   0        0
11           1     12                   1        1
12           2      1                   0        0
13           2      2                   1        1
14           2      3                   1        2
15           2      4                   0        0
16           2      5                   0        0
17           2      6                   1        1
18           2      7                   0        0
19           2      8                   0        0
20           2      9                   0        0
21           2     10                   1        1
22           2     11                   0        0
23           2     12                   0        0
```

Comment: Couldn't I simply set axis=1 to use the rows? But the problem of having the value of a row/col depending from the value of the previous row/col still remains

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you first set `CustomerID` as index and transpose your dataframe.

then apply your custom function.

i.e. something like:

```
df.T.apply(custom_func)
```

Comment: but how do I make the function take two consecutive values?